# Jquery tabs changing before fade animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've wanted to do smooth transition between tabs (first fadetoggle, then change content, fadetoogle again), but "changing content" part doesn't wait for the animation to finish. I.e. content changes before finishing the animation

```
$('.catalog__wrapper').fadeToggle('slow', executeTabChange(tab, () => $('.catalog__wrapper').fadeToggle()))
```

Link to jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/Denchuk10111/cowypes2/34/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.catalog__tabs').on('click', 'li:not(.catalog__tab_active)', function() {
        const tab = $(this);
        $('.catalog__wrapper').fadeOut('slow', () => {
            executeTabChange(tab, ()=>{
                $('.catalog__wrapper').fadeIn()
            });
        });
      });

      function executeTabChange(form, callback) {
        form
          .addClass('catalog__tab_active').siblings().removeClass('catalog__tab_active')
          .closest('body').find('div.catalog__content').removeClass('catalog__content_active')
          .eq(form.index()).addClass('catalog__content_active');
          callback();
      }

    })
```

Comment: It works now! But i don't understand why; Is this because i was _calling_ a function in the fadeOut parameters instead of _passing_ it as a callback?